# Is INSERT on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE better than inverse?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, innodb

(On MySQL, InnoDB) I am not directly checking if a certain record exists, instead I do that check *lazily* : I am normaly using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`. At some points of my code, the probability of an existing record is higher than absence of it, in that case I plan to do:

- `UPDATE ...`
- If `affected_rows<1 INSERT IGNORE INTO..`

Would this perform better than using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should pick the best method for each specific situation.

Comment: It depends on a lot of factor. If your server and your client are not on the same hardware, `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` might be better because it does not require a second round-trip.

Comment: I've never been a fan of the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` method; every developer I've seen use it regularly seems to end up getting bitten by it eventually. However, I have heard some strong arguments in favor of it to prevent concurrency issues on busy systems. All that said, affected_rows may not a good solution either, depending on the `SET` of the update; affected_rows will be 0 if the row(s) exist and the sets do not change the current values.